# Globalizing variables in sub functions doesnt work

Tags: python

My problem is simple.

This code,

```
def first():
    x = "hello"
    def second():
        global x
        x = "goodbye"
    second()
first()
```

does not work, since globalizing a variable declared inside a function isn't valid. If it was just one function I know it would, but how could I get this to work like this?

Comment: why do you need globals like this?

Comment: What is the expected output of this program?

Comment: There wouldnt be an output, x would be set to "goodbye". I need to do this in order to use recursion.

Comment: I don't get it.You want the x variable to be 'goodbye'.while calling x outside this function am i right?

Comment: How does this (global variables and nested functions) helps with recursion at all? Clear XY problem.

Comment: Read more about scope in python. The LEGB model https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/#:~:text=The%20Python%20scope%20concept%20is,resolving%20names%20in%20a%20program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem :**
The problem is there are two different `x` variables getting confused. The `x` in `second()` is global and can be printed out after running after running your code. The problem is the first `x` is considered a local in `first()`. You can check it on your own by copy-pasting the following code in different places to understand how the code considers the variable:

```
if 'x' in locals():
    print("local")
elif 'x' in globals():
    print("global")
else:
    print("unedfined")
```

**Solution 1**:
Always having x as a global by adding `global x` right on the line after `def first()` (and keeping it after `def second()`)

**Solution 2**:
Accepting not having globals. Instead you can `return x` at the end of your functions and assigning an other variable (that could have the same name) to the returned value of the function eg.`x = second()`. Then using that variable as an argument eg. `def first(x):`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a variable as global before you write to it in each of the functions. Like so:

```py
def first():
    global x
    x = "hello"
    def second():
        global x
        x = "goodbye"
    second()
first()
print(x)
# >>> goodbye
```

I'd recommend a different structure to your project though

Answer (score 0):

What I understood, you can initialize x variable before the function and then assign value to it when you want like this:

```
x = ''
def first():
    x = "hello"
    def second():
        x = "goodbye"
    second()
first()
```